# Exception when calling webservice with JSF Primefaces: Could not find backup for factory javax.faces.component.visit.Visit ContextFactory

Tags: jsf, primefaces

When calling a webservice using `JaxWsDynamicClientFactory` through JSF I always got this eception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find backup for factory javax.faces.component.visit.Visit ContextFactory
```

Anybody has a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i Just upgrade JSF-api  from 2.2.6 to 2.2.12

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.12</version>
</dependency>
```